# Django - prevent custom context processors loading on every page

Tags: django

I have a large project which has various applications within it. Each app has a number of page with some variables I want on each page of the app. To this end I have written custom context processors for each.

in my settings.py:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    ...
    "app_one.custom_context_processors.base_items",
    "app_two.custom_context_processors.base_items",
    "app_two.custom_context_processors.keyword_cloud",
    ...
)
```

My question is - how do I prevent `app_two` from loading the `app_one` custom context processor and vice versa, or is there a better way to implement this entirely?

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Template context processors are global, i.e. they apply to every request by nature. You can muck around with the request object to conditionally send different values as the return value, but you can't "stop" one.

Comment: OK, thanks. Then given what i am trying to achieve - what is the best way forward?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: A base set of variables present on each page of the different apps. I.e. all pages in in `app_one` have access to `app_one.custom_context_processors.base_items` and all pages in `app_two` to `app_two.custom_context_processors.base_items` but in a mutual exclusive way.